# File.Open encoding broken for rendered HTML Entities

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I have a directory with of 300+ HTML files that I need to parse data from and place into a new HTML template which works well with the exception of pre-rendered HTML Entities such as square root `√` that appear in some of the files. I have read a ton of posts over the last few hours about encoding in Ruby 1.9 and tried things like:

```
File.read( "_pending/testdir/filename.html", :encoding=>"UTF-8" )
```

and

```
trans = Iconv.new( 'UTF-8', 'IBM437' )
input_text = File.read( "_pending/testdir/filename.html" )
output_text = trans.iconv( input_text )
puts output_text
```

All with no luck. Once converted the square root symbol still appears as `âˆš` in the browser as well as in the raw HTML markup with the exception of the `Iconv` solution which outputs `AªAo` to console when it `puts`.

> **Setup**
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]

The encoding name returns `IBM437` when I do `HTML_FILE.external_encoding.name`.

Comment: Are you sure they're 'IBM437'? [Win-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) are more likely candidates. An alternate is to do a pre-pass and gsub the checkmarks into entities.

Comment: I agree, seems odd however when I run the below I get `IBM437`.

`test = File.open( "filename.html" )
puts test.external_encoding.name
test.close`

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, it turns out that I'm just an idiot and Ruby wasn't an issue at all... thanks for looking into this on my behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You have to be kidding me...*

The fix was to set a content header in the HTML template page. I'm guessing the console was outputting valid UTF-8 but not in a recognizable format.

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

While I feel pretty stupid right now, I'm sure someone else is going to run into something similar so if that's you: I feel your pain; I just hope you didn't spend the last 6 hours troubleshooting as I have.

Comment: Mixed encodings with HTTPd servers vs. the actual content, is a real pain when spidering and doing content analysis on the web. And, even if the server and HTML headers agree, the user can inject raw 8-bit and unicode characters into a document in a multitude of ways. Trying to write code to defend against it can be a real brain-burner.